# how to create a status bar in dialogbox created using CreateDialog(..) there is no option existes for "Status Bar"

Tags: api, winapi, dialog, statusbar, resource-editor

I am developing a visual c++ winapi application and i have created a dialog which is acapable f rendering images on

it.
you can see on this link - http://prntscr.com/1k8lla

the problem is i also have to create a strip like as you can see at the bottom of the window in black colour. I

want to do that same.

I got a suggestion to do the same using "Status Bar" in CreateWindow() but i have created this dialog window using

CreateDialog(); so when i see in the preoperties of the dialog it don't have any option for "Status Bar".

Comment: Manually adding Status Bar class to resource file?

Comment: Your question is about adding status bar, not scrolling.

Comment: yaah but that has been done. This was the new problem of winapi. If you want you can answer it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146173/scrollbar-not-taking-the-page-down-on-down-draggingon-dragging-it-go-back-to-it

Answer (score 1):

This MFC sample app adds a status bar to a dialog:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccstww6w(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: yaah you are write but i have created it manually and it is working .